# Priority Queue in swift

Tags: algorithm, swift, priority-queue

I'm trying to implement a version of Dijkstra Algorithm to find the shortest route for a bus to take from start to end. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find a library or other way that swift provides a type of priority queue so it seems I will have to code my own.

This being said, can anyone point me in the right direction to do this?

Currently my thinking is as follows:

Write a class which will hold the priority array. In this class there will be a method which receives a value, adds it to the priority array and then sorts it according to priority (In this case, distance). There will also be a get function which returns the highest priority item from the array.

I would like to know if I'm close or still way off in my understanding of a priority queue.

Thank you.

**EDIT :**

This is my code so far. Seems too short and brutal... I must be missing something in terms of the concept.

```
var priorityQueue = Dictionary<String, Int>()
var firstElement: String = ""

func push(name: String, distance: Int)
{
    priorityQueue[name] = distance
    var myArr = Array(priorityQueue.keys)
    var sortedKeys = sort(myArr) {
        var obj1 = self.priorityQueue[$0] // get obj associated w/ key 1
        var obj2 = self.priorityQueue[$1] // get obj associated w/ key 2
        return obj1 > obj2
    }

    firstElement = myArr[0]
    var tempPriorityQueue = Dictionary<String, Int>()
    for val in myArr
    {
        tempPriorityQueue[val] = priorityQueue[val]
    }

    priorityQueue = tempPriorityQueue
}

func pop() -> String
{
    priorityQueue.removeValueForKey(firstElement)
}
```

Comment: That's roughly correct. The method will take in value and a priority key as arguments. It will find where in the internal data structure that holds the pairs to place it based on the priority key. 

Now think about how you would set up that data structure. You need a data structure that is easy to add in the middle of, easy to remove from, and easy to get to the beginning of. You don't necessarily have to sort anything if you can find where to put the pairs in to begin with (it will sort itself).

Comment: Write some code and post it for more helpful feedback. There are also a wealth of resources here and online that have implementation details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dijkstra's algorithm with priority queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959634/dijkstras-algorithm-with-priority-queue)

Comment: Thank you @Al.Sal, I'll post some code soon. I have a better idea of what I need to do now.

Comment: @kurast, I saw that question. My one differs as it was swift specific if someone had some advice on where to look. That question also includes things like updating surrounding nodes etc which mine does not. Don't be so quick to judge a question negatively before you try see it from the OP's point of view.

Comment: I believe that you can still use `CFBinaryHeap` from Swift. However, the C API with pointers and stuff is so ugly to use from Swift that it might not be worth it.

Comment: @newacct yeah I looked into CFBinaryHeap. Between the difficulty in getting it to work, making it work nicely with swift and with the lack of helpful tutorials online, I didn't get very far with that approach.

Answer (score 2):

You should use heap sort for the priority. I think this is optimal! Try it out in playground!

```
import Foundation
typealias PriorityDefinition<P> = (_ p1: P, _ p2: P) -> (Bool)
class PriorityQueue<E, P: Hashable> {
    var priDef: PriorityDefinition<P>!
    var elemments = [P: [E]]()
    var priority = [P]()
    init(_ priDef: @escaping PriorityDefinition<P>) {
        self.priDef = priDef
    }
    func enqueue(_ element: E!, _ priorityValue: P!) {
        if let _ = elemments[priorityValue] {
            elemments[priorityValue]!.append(element)
        } else {
            elemments[priorityValue] = [element]
        }
        if !priority.contains(priorityValue) {
            priority.append(priorityValue)
            let lastIndex = priority.count - 1
            siftUp(0, lastIndex, lastIndex)
        }
    }
    func dequeue() -> E? {
        var result: E? = nil
        if priority.count > 0 {
            var p = priority.first!
            if elemments[p]!.count == 1 {
                if priority.count > 1 {
                    let _temp = priority[0]
                    priority[0] = priority[priority.count - 1]
                    priority[priority.count - 1] = _temp
                    p = priority.last!
                    siftDown(0, priority.count - 2)
                }
                result = elemments[p]!.removeFirst()
                elemments[p] = nil
                priority.remove(at: priority.index(of: p)!)
            } else {
                result = elemments[p]!.removeFirst()
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    func siftDown(_ start: Int, _ end: Int) {
        let iLeftChild = 2 * start + 1
        if iLeftChild <= end {
            var largestChild = priDef(priority[iLeftChild], priority[start]) ? iLeftChild : start
            let iRightChild = 2 * start + 2
            if iRightChild <= end {
                if priDef(priority[iRightChild], priority[iLeftChild]) {
                    largestChild = iRightChild
                }
            }
            if largestChild == start {
                return
            } else {
                let _temp = priority[start]
                priority[start] = priority[largestChild]
                priority[largestChild] = _temp
                siftDown(largestChild, end)
            }
        }
    }
    func siftUp(_ start: Int, _ end: Int, _ nodeIndex: Int) {
        let parent = (nodeIndex - 1) / 2
        if parent >= start {
            if priDef(priority[nodeIndex], priority[parent]) {
                let _temp = priority[nodeIndex]
                priority[nodeIndex] = priority[parent]
                priority[parent] = _temp
                siftUp(start, end, parent)
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
    func isEmpty() -> Bool {
        return priority.count == 0
    }
}
let Q = PriorityQueue<Int, Int> { (p1: Int, p2: Int) -> (Bool) in
    return p1 > p2
}
let n = 999
for i in 0...n - 1 {
    let start = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    Q.enqueue(i, i)
    let end = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    print(end - start)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code for "heapsort". Heapsort creates a "heap" which is basically a priority queue with the largest element first, then it repeatedly pops off the largest element of the heap = priority queue, moves it to the end of the array, and adds the previously last array element to the priority queue.

Inserting and removing items in a priority queue **must** be a O (log n) operation. That's the whole point of a priority queue. Calling "sort" while adding an element to the priority queue is absolutely absurd and is going to **totally kill** your performance.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in looking at two open source projects that I've authored. The first is SwiftPriorityQueue: https://github.com/davecom/SwiftPriorityQueue

Your implementation of a priority queue sorts on push which is O(n lg n). Most implementations of a priority queue, including SwiftPriorityQueue, use a binary heap as the backing store. They have push operations that operate in O(lg n) and pops that operate in O(lg n) as well. Therefore your suspicions are right - your current implementation is unlikely to be very performant (although pops are technically faster).

The second is SwiftGraph: https://github.com/davecom/SwiftGraph

SwiftGraph includes an implementation of Dijkstra's Algorithm.

I'm surprised neither of these projects was easier to find since they have been out for over a year and moderately popular, but based on current answers to this question in the last year, it seems I need to work on discoverability.